# Custom nameservers not resolving on Debian 11 on Hetzner root server

Tags: debian, networking, resolv.conf

I am at my wits end. I've spent the last two days trying to set custom nameservers on a Debian 11 Bullseye installation. Debian is installed through Hetzner's `installimage` script.

Now, the [recursive nameservers](https://docs.hetzner.com/dns-console/dns/general/recursive-name-servers/) provided by Hetzner do work and name resolving works, but as soon as I change the entries in `/etc/resolv.conf`, the thing stops.

Working `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 185.12.64.2
nameserver 185.12.64.1
```

Console output

```
root@localhost ~ # dig stackoverflow.com ns

; <<>> DiG 9.16.15-Debian <<>> stackoverflow.com ns
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 16463
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;stackoverflow.com.             IN      NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
stackoverflow.com.      86400   IN      NS      ns-1033.awsdns-01.org.
stackoverflow.com.      86400   IN      NS      ns-cloud-e2.googledomains.com.
stackoverflow.com.      86400   IN      NS      ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com.
stackoverflow.com.      86400   IN      NS      ns-358.awsdns-44.com.

;; Query time: 16 msec
;; SERVER: 185.12.64.2#53(185.12.64.2)
;; WHEN: Sat Nov 20 09:12:13 CET 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 178
```

Not working `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 9.9.9.9
```

Console output

```
root@localhost ~ # dig stackoverflow.com ns

; <<>> DiG 9.16.15-Debian <<>> stackoverflow.com ns
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I've also tried adding `dns-nameserver 1.1.1.1` to `/etc/network/interfaces`, but to no avail.

How could I start using non-Hetzner nameservers?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Also please note I am not a Linux veteran.

Comment: It looks like Hetzner (or maybe your own severs? are they virtual or colo or VPS?) are blocking port 53 except to Hetzner's own name servers.   If it's Hetzner, the only thing you can do is ask them to remove the block for your servers.  If it's iptables rules on your own servers (run `iptables -L -v -n`  to check) then delete them, and find out what startup scripts/config files are setting those rules and delete them from there too.

Comment: Does `dig @1.1.1.1 ns stackoverflow.com` return you anything? That uses `dig` to send DNS packets directly to the target server, further partitioning the problem

Comment: @cas That machine is bought through their server auction, so bare metal colo. As for the support, they are incredibly unhelpful. Stating that regarding root servers, they do not offer software support. Also that iptables command returns no rules. Also, when running Hetzner's VPS machines, the above working `/etc/resolv.conf` works fine.

Comment: @roaima The dig command times out. So I'm guessing it has to do with Hetzner blocking that specific port, because `ping 1.1.1.1` works well.

Comment: Sounds like it, doesn't it. Seems a strange thing for Hetzner to block. Might be worth querying it with them

Comment: Sorry to necro - Did you ever figure this out? I hit a similar issue and realised that I must explicitly allow a firewall allow rule for return packets from TCP requests. Check this doc, maybe it will explain or help the next person https://docs.hetzner.com/robot/dedicated-server/firewall/#out-going-tcp-connections